# Enum in custom web test validation rule

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webtest, validationrules

I'm building a Web Test using Microsoft VS2010.
I used the explanation on MSDN: [How to: Create a Custom Validation Rule for a Web Performance Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182556.aspx).
In the example there using `string` and `int` as private members with public "get" and "set" those parameters valid for edit in the UI when I add this validation rule to my test.

I want to have an Enum with 3 option that when I add the validation rule to the UI I can choose from.

Is there a way to add an Enum variable which will also be valid in the UI ?
Are there any other types which can be used which will be valid in the UI ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the UI only shows **String** and **primitive**-type properties in user-created rules/plugins.  Yet some built-in rules/plugins use **enums**... how can this be?  Thanks to the magic of the disassember and some detective work, we discover that it only accepts enums whose assembly name contains the string "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework".

So if you go to the trouble of compiling your enums (or indeed, your entire project) into an assembly called, for example, "MyEnums.Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework", BOOM your enum-typed properties will happily appear in the editor UI.