# How can I pass a list of values as a parameter to a Visual Studio web performance test or load test plugin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, load-testing, web-testing

Want to pass a list of values as a parameter to a Visual Studio web performance test or load test plugin?

Pages such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243191(v=vs.110).aspx explain the basics of how to create a plugin and I have several simple plugins. But there is very little details on how to specify the properties (ie parameters) for the plugin. From examples I have found C# code such as

```
public class MyPlugin : WebTestPlugin
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Simple string parameter")]
    [System.ComponentModel.Category("The category")]
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("Description of the simple string")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("The default value")]
    public string MySimpleString { get; set; }
```

The type could be `int` or `bool` as well as `string`. But I would like an array (or list or collection) of strings.

When the **Test mix** property of a load test is viewed, it is shown as `(collection)` and when selected an ellipsis appears. Clicking the ellipsis opens an editor for the list of tests. Something similar would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, plugin property values are indeed limited to bool, string and numeric types.  This restriction is hard-coded within the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework assembly.  There is no way to support other types (well, with [one exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14929540/426028)) or get any enhanced editor features such as in your Test Mix collection example.

If you want a property to accept a list of strings, for example, the only option is to have a property of type string, and parse the string into a list by splitting on a delimiter.  Disappointing, but true.