# how to create password property on loadtest plugin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, performance-testing, webtest

I created small loadtest plugin in Visual Studio.

Plugin has Password property:

```
[DisplayName("Password")]
[Description("Set your password")]
public string Password {get; set}
```

But password don't replace to asterisks on Property windows.

How to create right password property, that password will replace to asterisks?

Comment: Add DataType annotation `[DataType(DataType.Password)]`

Comment: Are you using winforms?  WPF?

Comment: DataType annotation doesn't work.

Comment: I think it is windows form, but I'm not sure. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243153.aspx

Comment: it has `using System.Windows.Forms;` in code sample

Comment: I do not think you can. Even if you could I think the password would be shown as plain text within the XML of the `.webtest` file. See also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746081/how-can-i-pass-a-list-of-values-as-a-parameter-to-a-visual-studio-web-performanc